# Throw custome exception to filter

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, webapi

I need to send from filter some status code, but i cant figure out how to pass the appropriate context exception. I saw HttpActionExecutedContext, but dont know where it is, in what namespace... Btw, its .net core 5, web api

```
   public class AuthFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
        {
            public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
            {
                if (context.Exception is CustomerDataException)
                {
    
                }
                else if (context.Exception is CustomerNotFoundException)
                {
    
                }
                else if (context.Exception is CustomerExistsException)
                { 
                
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HttpActionExecutedContext` is used as parameter in `ActionFilterAttribute` in **asp.net** web api by default.

For your scenario, it seems you want to send the status code from ExceptionFilter, you could do like below:

```
public class AuthFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        var statusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        if (context.Exception is CustomerDataException)
        {
            statusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        }
        else if (context.Exception is CustomerNotFoundException)
        {
            statusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
        }
        context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)statusCode;
        context.Result = new JsonResult(new
        {
            error = new[] { context.Exception.Message },
            statusCode = statusCode,
            stackTrace = context.Exception.StackTrace
        });
    }
}
```